# Changing an Existing class - Best Practice Open/Closed Principle

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am trying to figure out the best way to change an existing class.

So the class is called `ExcelReport` and it has one method `Create(data,headings)`. This is live and used in many places. Now recently I want to change the method so I can format columns in Excel.

```
Create(data, headings, columnformats)
```

So as not to upset my existing programs the best I can come up with is to add another method `Create2(data,headings,columnformats)` to the class.

I got a lot of suggestions saying I should modify the existing class with a overloaded method, which I did. But does this not break the Open/Close Principle as my existing class was in production?

Should I have created a new class `ExcelReport2(and Interface)` with the new improved method and passed this into my new program using dependency injection?

Answer (score 1):

**OCP**

> In object-oriented programming, the open–closed principle states "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification";[1] that is, such an entity can allow its behaviour to be extended without modifying its source code.

**Your solution**

You will most likely want to create more options later on for this.
And since you asked for an open/closed principle answer we need to take that into account (open for extension, closed for change).

A more robust alternative is to create a new overload:

```
void Create(CreationOptions options);
```

Looks trivial, right? The thing is that any subclass can introduce their own options like `MyPinkThemedFormattedCellsCreationOptions`.

So your new option class would look like this as of now:

```
public class CreationOptions
{
    public SomeType Data { get; set; }
    public SomeType Headings { get; set; }
    public SomeType[] ColumnFormats { get; set; }
}
```

That's open for extension and closed for change as new features doesn't touch the existing API, since now you only have to create sub classes based on `CreationOptions` for new features.

Comment: Interesting. You were right about my misinterpretation of the OCP, I removed my answer.

Comment: For this to work without having to modify Create on future extensions, the formatting logic would need to be in CreationOptions, right? Otherwise, you'd need to modify Create to support the new options.

Comment: Yes, or you can introduce formatters that can be registered in the main class as extensions. And those formatters act using the creation options. But it's very hard to give an advice there since the design varies a lot depending on the use case.

Comment: If I am being asked to add a new overloaded method. void Create(CreationOptions options); I am changing my existing class and breaking OCP ?

Comment: Yes, but you do it to be able to adhere to the principal. No programmer is perfect or can write the perfect code. We learn, adapt and write better code every day.